# Best Practice in Re-Using a Cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm building a program that will repopulate an Employee's new record based on his/her old records.
Just a sample concept: `x_table` holds the employee records. Record with `ID` 1 is the initial record and 2 is his new one.

```
create x_table 
(
    id          number,
    value       varchar2(100)    
);

insert into x_table (id, value ) values (1, 'One');
insert into x_table (id, value ) values (2, 'Two');

commit;
```

the sample dummy packaged procedure `this_is_a_pkg.do_something` updates his her records.

in terms of performance, which is the best way to re-use the Explicit cursor `x_cur` (below)?

**Using the Same Explicit Cursor but multiple Type Declarations**

```
declare

    cursor  x_cur (p_id number) is
    select  *
    from    x_table;

    type   x_type is table of x_cur%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    x_rec  x_type;
    x_rec2 x_type;

begin

    open    x_cur(1);
    fetch   x_cur
    bulk collect
    into    x_rec;
    close   x_cur;

    open    x_cur(2);
    fetch   x_cur
    bulk collect
    into    x_rec2;
    close   x_cur;

    for i in 1..x_rec2 loop -- outer loop because this is the new record

        for x in 1..x_rec loop -- outer loop because this is the old record

            this_is_a_pkg.do_something(p_new_id     => x_rec2(i).id
                                       p_old_value  => x_rec(x).value)

        end loop;

    end loop;


end;
```

**Using the Different Explicit Cursor and Multiple Type Declarations**

```
declare

    cursor  x_cur (p_id number) is
    select  *
    from    x_table;

    cursor  x_cur2 (p_id number) is
    select  *
    from    x_table;

    type   x_type is table of x_cur%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    x_rec  x_type;
    x_rec2 x_cur2;

begin

    open    x_cur(1);
    fetch   x_cur
    into    x_rec;
    close   x_cur;

    open    x_cur(2);
    fetch   x_cur
    into    x_rec2;
    close   x_cur;

    for i in 1..x_rec2 loop -- outer loop because this is the new record

        for x in 1..x_rec loop -- outer loop because this is the old record

            this_is_a_pkg.do_something(p_new_id     => x_rec2(i).id
                                       p_old_value  => x_rec(x).value)

        end loop;

    end loop;


end;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: In most cases the best way to use a `CURSOR` is not to use it... Don't know, what this SP is doing, but - in most cases - set based approaches are superior...

Comment: the SP in the question is just a dummy SP, in my real-world scenario, its an Oracle EBS Seeded API. what do you mean by "set based" approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do cursor `overloading` which would save the memory space, make the code consistent and increase readability. There is `NO` significant performance improvement just because of using `Overloading`.

The process of "overloading" originates in the world of object-oriented coding with the concept of polymorphism.  It is the idea that the functionality of a `PL/SQL` stored procedure or function can be changed based on the input datatype.

As per [Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2797561100346394673) the only benefit of overloading is "ease of use".

Comment: Does the concept of Function overloading in PL/SQL also apply to cursors?

Comment: `Overloading` is a concept which can be applied to procedure/function/cursor etc.